# Recover MySQL database on windows with ibdata1, ib_logfile and mysql-bin.00000 files

Tags: mysql, windows, recovery

I have a problem with MySQL database in a WAMP environment. I dropped my database via phpmyadmin and now I am trying to recover it. I created a new database with the same name and I imported some data to correct the database, but it was not enough.

Now I need your help to restore data from the `mysql-bin` or `ibdata1` directories. So please help me:

[image]

How can I recover data using the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile1`, `ib_logfile0` and `mysql-bin.000001` files on Windows 7?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. However, we do expect a certain quality of questions asked. Please consider revising your question and adding relevant information . Otherwise your question might be closed as **unclear what you're asking**. E.g. your screenshot doesn't have anything to do with the database restore process. You might want to consider adding relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, **ibdata1** contains the tables `metadata and change buffer` and **ib_logfiles** are having `innodb redo logs`.

So the important thing is to being your **ibdata1** first, the only way use any recovery software, or if you have **MySQLdump** then restore it.